# Solaris 32 bit - build shared object using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, solaris, shared-libraries

I am trying to crate a shared object (.so) using gcc version 3.4.3 for Solaris 32 bit system. I was googling for flags required to create a shared object for solaris. In some of the posts , I see that "-shared" flag  not used. Instead "-G" flag is used. I had an impression that "-G" flag is same as "-g", but it seems that "-G" is equivalent to "-shared". Am I correct?

The reason being that with SLES10 x86_64 systems, "-shared" flag was required to build .so.

I tried following:-

```
LIB=-L/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib
gcc -m32 -G -fPIC -o myapi.so.1 myapi.o $(LIB)
```

Do I need to change above to:-

```
gcc -m32 -shared -fPIC -o myapi.so.1 myapi.o $(LIB)
```

**Update1**
Helpful suggestion from 
@user562374 to use -shared flag.

If the shared object built using -shared is deployed on solaris machine using different compiler and if it is "statically" linked, will it cause any issues? When I say "statically" linked .so, I mean shared object is linked in make file rather then using "dlsym".

Comment: That's not what "statically" linked means.   Static linking means copies the sections of a .a library you need into your binary instead of using a shared object.    If the shared object works with dlopen it should work with a normal dynamic library link (the thing you incorrectly called "statically").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   -G num
       Put global and static objects less than or equal to num
       bytes into the small data or bss sections instead of the
       ...
```

If it's gcc, it's `-shared`, because `-G` has other uses.

Comment: @user562374..Thanks for a quick response. If the shared object built using -shared is deployed on solaris machine using different compiler and if it is "statically" linked, will it cause any issues? When I say "statically" lined .so, I mean shared object is linked in make file rather then using "GetProcAddress".